# php max execution time ignoring php.ini

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am trying to export a large database via phpMyAdmin. I jeep getting an error that the script stopped because the maximum execution time of 600 seconds was reached (or something like that). I tried setting `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` to 0 and -1. The change takes effect as I can see it in `phpinfo()`, but I am still getting the error. Another strang thing is that originally (before I changed it to 0) it wasn't 600 either. It was 180! Where is this 600 set?

Comment: Have you restarted apache (just throwing idea)?

Comment: Could be the timeout setting on your webserver

Comment: are you sure you are changing the correct php.ini?

Comment: Why you don's use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)?

Comment: @NicholasKing Like I said, I see the changes in phpinfo(), so they are taking effect.

Comment: have you tried with  setting  .htaccess rule max_execution_time or php max_execution_time function ?

Comment: @BhavinRana I thought `max_execution_time` could only be set in `php.ini`. I will check if phpMyAdmin may be overriding it somewhere.

Comment: @ZombieHunter phpMyAdmin allows for many settings, such as output compatible with other databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if it is manually set somewhere. Assuming you are on a UNIX type platform:

```
find /path/to/root/of/phpmyadmin -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "max_execution_time"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your web server can have other timeout configurations that may also interrupt PHP execution. Apache has a Timeout directive and IIS has a CGI timeout function. See your web server documentation for specific details.

Don't use phpMyAdmin to import large files. Try using the mysql CLI to import a dump of your DB. Transfer the SQL file to the server and execute the following on the server using PHP script like shell_exec or system

> mysql --user=user --password=password database < database_dump.sql.

Of course the database has to exist, and the user you provide should have the necessary privilege(s) to update the database.